'RunnableSequence' object has no attribute 'prompt' error
I wanted to setup a chain as follows:
reduce_prompt = hub.pull("rlm/reduce-prompt")
reduce_chain = reduce_prompt | llm_model
combine_documents_chain = StuffDocumentsChain(
  llm_chain=reduce_chain, 
  document_variable_name="doc_summaries")

It gave me an error AttributeError: 'RunnableSequence' object has no attribute 'prompt'
I am not sure what it means. If I change the runnable line reduce_chain = reduce_prompt | llm_model to reduce_chain = LLMChain(prompt = reduce_prompt, llm=llm_model) such that the full code :
reduce_prompt = hub.pull("rlm/reduce-prompt")
reduce_chain = LLMChain(prompt = reduce_prompt, llm=llm_model)
combine_documents_chain = StuffDocumentsChain(
  llm_chain=reduce_chain, 
  document_variable_name="doc_summaries")

my code would run without errors. Could you help explain what went wrong in the original code?

Just remove the StuffDocumentsChain and directly call the reduce_chain using the invoke() method with the parameters for your embedded variable; i.e.,
invoke({"var_name_in_prompt": variable_with_data})

It dynamically uses the Chain, and LangChain will soon remove the support for chains altogether and just use runnable sequences.
